# How to create google plus circle with mouseover effect?

Tags: javascript

Those of you who have seen google plus may know what Im taking about...

Essentially my problem is this. I would like to have a circle with radius for example of some number of pixels with text in the center. On mouseover, the outline of the circle expands by whatever it was plus 5. When I mouse out, the circle gradually shrinks back to its original size. If the text in the middle of the circle is clicked then an alert box of some sort pops up.

What is a good way to do this and how? Does it involve div tags?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS3 border-radius to create your circle and some JS to do the animations...or you could try to do them with CSS3 as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/DOSBeats/cE6Yb/

This version uses JS.

Comment: is it possible to keep the text in the center unmoved, and expand the circle in all 4 directions as opposed to expanding just from the right side and bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS code they use:

```
.eswd {
background: url("/images/experiments/nav_logo78.png") repeat scroll 0 -243px transparent;
}

.esw {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 0 none;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline;
height: 15px;
margin-left: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
vertical-align: 6px;
width: 24px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button g:pingback="/gen_204?atyp=i&amp;ct=plusone&amp;cad=S0" title="Recommend this page" g:undo="poS0" g:type="plusone" g:entity="http://anewyorkthing.com/" onmouseover="window.gbar&amp;&amp;gbar.pw&amp;&amp;gbar.pw.hvr(this,google.time())" onclick="window.gbar&amp;&amp;gbar.pw&amp;&amp;gbar.pw.clk(this)" class="esw eswd" style="" id="gbpwm_0"></button>
```